# Triple boot Mac OS X, Debian and Gentoo on a MacBook

Tags: linux, macbook, grub, multi-boot, refit

I'm looking to install Debian and Gentoo alongside Mac OS X on a (Intel) MacBook. Debian will be for using Linux, and Gentoo for toying around. There are lots of guides on the Internet about dual booting, but I haven't found any on triple booting two Linux distributions and Mac OS X...

I'm thinking something along the lines of using [rEFIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REFIt) and [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) - but maybe only GRUB is the way to go.

What to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer at http://wiki.debian.org/MacBook/DebianInstallTutorial

Thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: feel free to accept your own answer.  if you can, improve it by writing up the main steps you took to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Just get a copy of VirtualBox (it's free) and install your experimental stuff on that. You will use less aggregate disk space and the performance impact is minimal, especially for non-production uses.

Comment: I'm not looking for virtualization (yet - I may give Xen a go later on); I want to be able to boot into the linuxes.

Answer (score 3):

The MintCast podcast just did an episode on Grub, which might be useful, but I would also go with virtualization, particularly if you are looking to try out multiple Linux dustributions.  VirtualBox is free and quite good, but in the same situation I chose to use VMWare Fusion, as their web site has many "appliances" - prebuilt virtual machines with Linux and other OSs, which makes installation very quick.

Comment: I'll look into that podcast!